# Android in-app purchases with free trial (without subscriptions)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I checked the Google [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) about the part concerning the free trials, the problem is that those free trials seem to be only applicable to the subscriptions.

Is there any way to setup free trials for the other kinds of in-app purchases? (in my case just normal products)

PS: I could try using the subscriptions, but I guess there will be an automated purchase activated once the period is over. I don't want of course to let them buy this subscription.

Comment: You could store some sort of ID (I think you can get the user's gmail account if you have that permission) on an external database (such as parse.com) to indicate when they've started the free trial.  Check the db and if the user isn't there, offer the free trial, and if they are, either unlock the feature/product or show that it's expired, depending on the date.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I will try to keep using the Google library to achieve that. I don't want to use an external database to follow-up.

Comment: If you're correct that the Play store doesn't support free trials for products, and I think you are, then you'll have to find some other way to track it.